# How to disable this orange warning line below the code in IntelliJ, it's annoying

Tags: clojurescript

[image]

I'm coding some clojurescript, and want to get rid of the annoying orange line. How can I turn it off completely ?

Comment: fix the warning. It's not just an orange line. It tries to tell you something. Also, I'm pretty sure you'll  be able to find the code highlighting and warning settings in intellij's settings.

Comment: It's IntellJ at the title

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What warnings do you get from the IDE ?

Comment: If you hover over the squiggly lines you will see what the warning wants to tell you. You can then switch it off most likely, but first you need to know what warning it is. It might be "cannot resolve" or "unused alias".

Comment: @ThanhHải Can you please tell us what the warnings are?